# How to configure Azure web Job for Always On

Tags: azure

My web job goes on sleep after a while
and as per Microsoft docs

"A web app can time out after 20 minutes of inactivity. Only requests to the scm (deployment) site or to the web app's pages in the portal reset the timer. Requests to the actual site don't reset the timer. If your app runs continuous or scheduled WebJobs, enable Always On to ensure that the WebJobs run reliably"

but I am not able to find this setting. Thats how web job looks like in portal

[image]

Can some one please help me , how can I turn on this setting

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#general-settings Scroll down a bit

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Web App that is hosting your WebJobs and select the Application Settings menu option. The Always On setting is there.

Note that Always On is only available for Basic or greater service tiers. Free and Shared do not have this setting.